# How to display data with three degrees of freedom on a chart?

Tags: statistics, data

I have a collection of data obtained from calculations and I want to display it on a chart or whiz-wheel or similar, to be used "in the field" as a low-tech solution, since no computer will be available.  I have a single output variable calculated from three inputs.  What I want to avoid is making a giant book of tables or charts, and instead use something like the whiz-wheel that reloaders use for calculating propellant weight.  Are there any nifty graphical devices out there that can display three degrees of freedom on one chart?

Comment: What about a custom slide rule? The Whiz wheel sounds like a good idea...

Comment: Funny, I was just staring at my slide rule, searching for inspiration.  The one I have still only allows for two degrees of freedom (position of the center slide and position of the cursor), but maybe I could add another slide.

Comment: Also, you might consider the pilot's whiz wheel (E6B). The trick is how to make one with your own data...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E6B

Comment: So far I've made a slide rule out of paper, with two slides and a cursor.  A typical slide rule has one slide.  It seems like I can just add as many slides as I need for each independent variable, but I'm still experimenting.  Eventually I would like to make the slides round, like the E6B.

Comment: For the details of how to construct charts for this kind of calculation, you might want to search for info on Nomography.

Answer (score 3):

Per @Dan's suggestion, I googled "nomography" and found an article titled "The Lost Art of Nomography" by Ron Doerfler, published in the UMAP Journal 30.4 (2009).  The article describes a compound-nomograph, which is pretty much what I need.  Here is a screen shot of such a device, taken from the article:

[image]

The image shows a nomograph for three independent variables, but the principle could be extended to any number of variables I believe.

Comment: Identifying the technique by name, citation and illustration is a good start but this would be an even better answer if it described the method for constructing such a graphic.